# Spread footing foundation for kitchen addition

Tags: foundation

I am in the process of doing about 200sqft addition on the first floor to my kitchen. The structural engineer did not visit my house and specified spread footing for the addition. My current house is on grade beam and piles. I live in San Francisco bay area. My house is on a flat area. City approved the plans. How concerned should I be?

Comment: not a structural engineer, but spread footing is used in some seismic locations .  Since it is recommended by an engineer and approved by the city, I would be confident with it.

Answer (score 1):

I can't see why you are concerned enough to even ask the question.

A site visit won't give the engineer much, if any, more information than they get from (probably quite extensive, given the history of the area) maps of the soils in the city. They will have designed something suitable for the soils, structure, and seismic zone. The city has concurred.

Comment: If this answer doesn’t allow you to sleep well, get a second opinion. You’ll probably pay $500-1000.